# How to split large time-related aggregates in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, sequential, aggregateroot, large-data-volumes

I am running into the following design problem, for which I haven't been able to find a satisfactory solution. Any guidance is welcome.

Consider a notion of route for a vehicle, where a route is a sequence of departures or arrivals at known places. For a given vehicle, there cannot be two events at the same time, and a departure must follow an arrival at that same place. One challenge here is the volume of data, as there might in several thousands of events for a given vehicle.

We have two main use cases:

- bulk update, where one replaces a fragment of a route with a new sequence of events
- Analyse the sequence of events (for a given vehicle) to detect various patterns.

What I have tried/thought so far:

- Use a single "route" aggregate for a given vehicle. It is easy, and enables ensuring the consistency of the event sequence, but will not scale, unfortunately.
- Use a "RouteFragment" aggregate that would represent the route of a vehicle between two given timestamps. That partly addresses the scalability issue (hopefully the two timestamps are not too far away), but I am not sure how to ensure consistency across fragments.
- Use a "Stopover" aggregate, which would represent an arrival followed by a departure from the same known place. The problem becomes ensuring that there are no two stopovers that overlap.
- Drop the idea of aggregate, and use some sort of service that would process and clean the sequence of events regularly. The repair logic is not obvious to me either.

Are there patterns or strategies within DDD to manage large volumes of sequential events while maintaining domain invariants? I don't quite see how guidance about aggregates applies (aggregates adhere to transaction boundaries, a transaction should touch only one aggregate, etc.)

How would you have approached that?

Comment: Why wouldn't a route aggregate scale?

Comment: In our case, the life cycle of a vehicle lasts for several years, possibly decades, and the number of events can be large, about several thousand per year. @alex-borodin has a point about "premature optimization", and the single route aggregate is what we have implemented, but, more generally, I am curious about aggregates whose consistency rules span over time.

Comment: I can assure you from experience: aggregates that are dealing with many tens of thousands of events per year are scalable, although to be fair, some of the patterns that DDD practitioners reach for (repository most notably) probably won't help.

Comment: What will be useful is to event source.

Comment: I have no experience with event sourcing. How would event sourcing avoid reloading the whole route to ensure that the sequence of arrival/departure is consistent?

Comment: Store the arrival/departure events in the persistence layer as distinct rows/documents or whatnot.  Your route aggregate becomes the sole writer of the validated (or at least: this seemed like it was valid at a time: you'll likely also need a retraction/replacement event) events (which allows it to enforce the transaction boundary: note that the term transaction here doesn't necessarily imply DB transaction).  It then only needs to read the events which are required to validate an incoming command.  Off-the-shelf event store implementations won't tend to support this out-of-the-box...

Comment: ...but I can say that I've used the aggregate abstraction (enforcing single writer per aggregate via Akka Cluster Sharding) with event sourcing (via Akka Persistence) with the median instance of an aggregate having tens of thousands of events per year: the trick in this case was to use multiple event-sourced actors to provide the aggregate behavior (the sharded actor would do a _lot_ of stashing in order to present an illusion that it's one actor).  Disclaimer: my current employer maintains Akka; the experience I write of is at a prior employer and I'd have posted this before my employment.

Comment: In some sense, from a persistence perspective, the persistence model I ended up using was `RouteFragment`s, but since there's a (distributed) pessimistic concurrency control wrapper around the fragments of a given route, `Route` was still the aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two things you can apply.

First 'GRASP Controller':

> Problem: Who should be responsible for handling an input system event?
> Solution: A use case controller should be used to deal with all system events of a use case and may be used for more than one use case.

In this case, it may mean that we should handle time-related things outside the domain, at the boundary of the outer layer of an application. It will simplify the task - instead of managing multiple events, you will think about the logic that saves events to DB and get an event or event list from the DB. Also, instead of deduplicating work, you can simply use transactions in DB to avoid duplication.

The next - is "Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil."

Memory and CPU time are cheap, and development time is expensive. According to K.Wiegers, increasing performance always decreases modifiability and vice versa. But, if your code is easy to modify, you can always change it for better performance.

So, you can start with the simplest possible thing: a single "route." If you find that its performance is unsuitable for the system, then you can modify it and improve its performance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not very familiar with the GRASP terminology. I understand that you would go for a simpler "repository" of events, and, given a new bulk of events, the controller would load the two events that directly precede and follow it and then check the consistency of of that stretch only ; pushing that to the DB provided it is valid. Am I right?

Comment: @fchauvel more or less correct. A couple of things: controller does not load events itself. It purpose is only to catch the input event and run proper business logic. The goal is to change complex async and multi-thread behaviour(events in time) into simple single-thread and sync. Also you can use transactions in DB to ensure that one event does not overwrite another. So, some validation logic will be performed by native DB features. And so, your business logic will need only to validate event's order.